# optimization, change in constraint equation.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

maximizing 
$z = 11x_1 + 4x_2 + x_3 +15x_4$

over

$3x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 +4x_4 \leq 28$
$8x_1 + 2x_2 - x_3 + 7x_4 \leq 50$

with $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \geq 0$

gives us a max of 106 a $(0,4,0,6)$ so $x_1$ and $x_3$ are free, the other two ($x_2,x_4$) are basic variables.

if you change the first solution from $28$ to say $28 + \delta$, determine the range on this $\delta$ s.t. $x_2,x_4$ remain basic variables in an optimal solution, and what would $z$ be then?

My initial intuition is that since the second constraint is fixed but the first is NOT, 
and that at $(0,4,0,6)$, we have

$3(0) + 4 + 2(0) + 4(6) = 28$ $\leq$ $28$

$\Rightarrow$ $\delta \in [0,\infty)$

but the zero case is the same so we rule that out, hence

$\delta \in (0,\infty)$

But I don't know where to go from here, (im pure math and this is an elective applied course), I want to say this IS my range for the $\delta$, and if it is, what is the new maximum $z$ value?

Thanks to anyone who can answer, also it is from Intro to Linear Programming and Game Theory Chapter 5 Section 5 by Keough and Thie
(problem 3, and the example is along it in next photo)

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Moo I am 100000% correct, I could take photos and upload if you'd like.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, I thought that was already a given, all of my problems in this course assume nonnegative variables at all times, any clue on how to determine $\delta$ or if I am headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider the dual problem
$$
\min(28y_1+50y_2)\\
\begin{cases}
3y_1+8y_2\ge 11,\\
y_1+2y_2\ge 4,\\
2y_1-y_2\ge 1,\\
4y_1+7y_2\ge 15,\\
\text{all }y_k\ge0.
\end{cases}
$$
For what $28+\delta$ the same solution $A:(2,1)$ holds? You can draw the level set $(28+\delta)y_1+50y_2=\text{const}$ and see on the picture.
[image]

Comment: so by considering the dual problem of the given primal problem is the way to go for this one? I have to wrap my head around this solution, but that seems like it'll work, thanks!

Comment: @eyeheartmath Do not forget the Complementary Slackness Principle. It relates the primal optimal with the dual optimal solutions.

Comment: thats right if the dual variable is slack then the corresponding primal constraint need be strict equality and vis versa, so there is this relationship between solutions of primal and dual, correct?

Comment: @eyeheartmath Right, and the other way round: slack primal gives equality in the dual (that corresponds to the point $A$).

Comment: awesome thanks so much! this makes total sense!! hence why you have the equalityy above that comes from having slacks in my primal, thank you a million!!

Comment: @eyeheartmath You are welcome :-)